# Can I set up a Raspberry Pi as a proxy to allow 3 different web servers to be used behind a single router on my home network?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have three web servers I would like to be able to access behind the same router.  How would I do that so that when the web address for Server A, B, or C is entered out on the internet, it goes to the right one?  If a Raspberry Pi can be used for this, can someone walk me through the process or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just to clarify an important point before answering: do you really mean that your router has **three** WAN IP addresses,or what you mean is that your three web servers have three different names, like *www.my_server1.com*, *www.my_other_server.edu*, and so on?

Comment: Assuming you have only a single public IP address you would not even need a Raspberry Pi to do that. Just set up one of the three web servers to be a Reverse Proxy for the other two and port forward any port 80 and/or 443 coming from outside to that server. Or you could set up an RPi to function as a Reverse Proxy for all three server. It's not very hard to set up with Apache (for example).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I mean that I have three domain names that I would like to be able to run web servers for on my network (single IP address).  Actually one of them is a NextCloud server.

Comment: @StarCat How do I set up a Reverse Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) is the way to handle this scenario.

> How do I set up a Reverse Proxy?

You need to install a web server such as Apache or Nginx which has this capability. Both of these web servers are available for Raspberry Pi.

*Apache Example*

Skipping over details specific to Linux/Raspberry Pi, you can use Apache [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) to accomplish your goal (specifically, [name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)).

**Overview**

- Install Apache on your Raspberry Pi (as needed).
- Set up your Raspberry Pi to receive all web requests on e.g. port 80 (this is usually accomplished by using port forwarding in your router).
- Ensure that the appropriate [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) modules are enabled in your Apache configuration. You'll likely want `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_http`, and `mod_proxy_html`, at minimum.
- Create Apache virtual hosts for each of your web addresses with appropriate `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` entries and IPs.

  *Example Host 1*

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName site1.example.com
  #ServerAlias *.site1.example.com
  #DocumentRoot "/unneeded"

  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.10/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.10/

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  *Example Host 2*

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName site2.example.com
  #ServerAlias *.site2.example.com
  #DocumentRoot "/unneeded"

  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.20/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.20/

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  *Example Host 3*

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName site3.example.com
  #ServerAlias *.site3.example.com
  #DocumentRoot "/unneeded"

  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.30/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.30/

  </VirtualHost>
  ```